# How to find out the number of useable addresses in a private class A network?

Tags: networking

I am studying networking and have come across this question.

I am asked to set up 14 separate IP networks that can each have up to 400 computers. What IANA private IP range should I select?

a. 10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255

b. 172.16.0.0-172.31.255.255

c. 192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255

d. 169.254.0.0-169.254.255.255

They say the answer is b, but I can't seem to figure out why this is?

Comment: Welcome to superuser: This does not really fit in the 'question' requirements as it looks like a school project and not a home user problem. I am sure someone knows the answer and may comment but it may also be reviewed as off topic. good luck   Please take a couple of minutes and read:- http://superuser.com/help , again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Comment: I'd be fine with closing _all_ homework questions which are for some reason about classful networks, just because they're actively harmful to the OP.

Comment: @grawity It boggles my mind that so many networking courses cover an addressing scheme that was phased out before many of the students were even born.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer isn't "b". The answer *used to be* "b" roughly 25 years ago – but then subnetting was invented, and later classless routing (CIDR) became a thing, and both completely changed the way you'd count and divide networks.

If your study material talks about "class A/B/C" networks in any other context than historical information, then it's very out of date.

---

So why *was* the answer "b", anyway?

Back when IP used entirely class-based networks, the ranges you listed were divided like this:

- 10.0.0.0–10.255.255.255 was a single class-A network, with 2^24 addresses.
- 172.16.0.0–172.31.255.255 was a group of 16 class-B networks, each with 2^16 addresses.
- 192.168.0.0–192.168.255.255 was a group of 256 class-C networks, each with 2^8 addresses.
- (169.254.0.0–169.254.255.255 was a *public* class-B network then, so let's ignore it.)

You can see that the 1st range only had a single classful network, and the 3rd range had many networks but they were much too small for 400 hosts each. So the 2nd range was the only choice.

---

However, as mentioned, subnetting is a thing. The private ranges *today* are divided like this:

- The first range is 10.0.0.0 with prefix length of 8 bits, or 10.0.0.0/8 in the short notation.
- The 2nd range is 172.16.0.0 with prefix length 12, or 172.16.0.0/12.
- The 3rd range is 192.168.0.0 with prefix length 16, or 192.168.0.0/16.
- (The 4th range, 169.254.0.0/16, is nowadays reserved for link-local communications and therefore unsuitable for routing. Let's ignore it again.)

With subnetting or CIDR there *isn't* a predefined number of networks in each range, nor a predefined netmask or prefix length – you can subdivide any range however you want.

Short reminder of calculating the required size: For `x` addresses, you need at least `ceil(log(x)/log(2))` "host" bits. Subtract that from 32, and you get the maximum "network" bits, i.e. the longest acceptable prefix length.

As you can see, all three ranges are sufficiently large to fit 14 subnets * 400 hosts (4 + 9 bits).